# Hibernate JPA Mapping Multiple Entities of the Same Type

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a one-to-many relationship with Customer and Address, but I'm not sure how to represent this with JPA. I don't want use @OneToMany for the AddressEntity's in CustomerEntity because I want to avoid wrapping it in a Collection.

I'm wondering what annotation or even other strategies I can use to maintain the relationship where one customer will, for simplicity, always have two addresses. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Address Entity

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "address")
public class AddressEntity
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @?
    private CustomerEntity customer;
}
```

Customer Entity

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "customer")
public class CustomerEntity
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @?
    private AddressEntity shippingAddress;

    @?
    private AddressEntity billingAddress;
}
```

Comment: With java,you can make your classes and annotations but why would you do that when it is provided. Using the annotations and Colllection framework will only reduce your work so you can focus on business logic.

Comment: Perhaps my question was not clear. I want to use existing annotations, I'm just unsure of the correct combination. I want to avoid use @OneToMany because I want to map the entity directly to the object instead of wrapping it in a Collection.

Comment: Well use a `@OneToOne`  if it is a single ended association!!

Comment: A little offtopic suggestion, but when it comes to order details, keep in mind that it is probably better to copy address data rather than link an address record. Address records can be changed (for example when people move), if you directly link an address to an order, the order history will change.

Comment: Wow @Gimby that is some great forethought! Would you have any recommendations on how to solve that problem? I have used auditing systems like Envers before but I'm not sure that would be a good idea to link an order to an audited address? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @PearsonRadu Whatever makes sure you don't have one address record. Copying the address data to an order, using an address versioning system, data warehousing, etc. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case when an address can belong different customers.

```
@Entity
public class AddressEntity
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

}

@Entity
public class CustomerEntity
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private AddressEntity shippingAddress;

    @ManyToOne
    private AddressEntity billingAddress;

}
```

if each customer has unique address, better to store the addresses in the same customer record.

You can create class `EmbeddedAddress` and use `@Embedded` and `@Embeddable` annotations.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I looked into the @ManyToOne approach and it works perfectly when the addresses can belong to multiple customers, like you mentioned. For my purpose, each address will correspond to a specific customer. I was trying to avoid the embedded route, but it might be a more clear to write it that way. Plus if I decide to move away from the embedded address, it would be easy to convert to it's own entity.

Comment: @PearsonRadu Always ready to help, Radu. We have used embedded approach in very large projects — it works well. Also keep in mind, as I remember, if you have all embedded fields `null`, you will have an embedded object `null` too.

Answer (score 1):

For your exact scenario, I think you could go for [@PostLoad](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PostLoad.html).
The steps would be:

- use `@OneToMany` annotation to load the addresses into a collection
- annotate both `shippingAddress` and `billingAddress` with [@Transient](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html)
- create a public method annotated with `@PostLoad`
- initialise your 2 transient fields (you need to have at least an enum to discriminate between the addresses)

Why would the steps above work?

- `PostLoad` is invoked after an entity is loaded from the database
- the fields need to be transient, because they are not mapped to database columns

A relevant example can be found [here](https://nullbeans.com/configuring-postload-and-postupdate-in-jpa-hibernate/).

While the approach above would solve your problem, it adds some degree of verbosity in your JPA entities. I would suggest to go for [@OneToMany](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html) and make sure you add an enum in `AddressEntity` to check if an address is for shipping or billing.

Also, given that you mentioned that there is a one-to-many relationship between a customer and an address, then there is a many-to-one relationship between an address and a customer. The annotation to use in the `AddressEntity` class is [@ManyToOne](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html)